SyncCenter and FritzBox NAS causes "process cannot access the file", is there a solution?
I am using a Samsung SSD 870 QVO SATA III 2.5 inch on the USB port of the FritzBox 6591 Cable: FRITZ!OS:7.58 (Vodafone, cannot update myself). SSD formatted as NTFS/GPT.
Both USB ports are set to power mode USB 3.0. I can access the data without problem and writing to the disk works as well (from different OSs and devices/Smart TV). Copying multiple Gigs of data also works.
Edit: Same issue with the FritzBox internal storage capacity. So this rules out the Samsung EVO as root cause.
Using Windows 10 SyncCenter I get
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

I followed the usual tips and trick like here.

Registry entry under http parameters
Restart http service
Reset network interface

SyncCenter with another NAS works with no issues. The other NAS can copy data to the FritzBox/SSD with no issues, even GBs. Only SyncCenter has the issue with the FritzBox/SSD, I can reproduce the issue on another Win10 PC.
I would be grateful for any tips.
--- Edit ----
On QNAP there was a similar issue years back:
https://forum.qnap.com/viewtopic.php?p=325147&sid=d0eb88281bf18fdbd5ce1bfe7a0e0b71
